# Performing File Transfer Activities using ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio, wsproxy

i am currently trying to create and and start Activites in Automation Studio and i am stuck at performing File Transfer activities. i made sure to preform a series of Data Extracts so that the files can be stored in safehouse and while i can run a data extract using automation studio the SSJS code gaves me a status error. and Salesforce Support Error stated that the filetransferActivityID: xxxxxxx was not found even though it matches the exact one found on the File transfer activity itself. current code below:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

    try {
      
        var action = "start";
        var properties = {
            ObjectID: "xxxxxxx" // replace with your file transfer activity's ObjectID
        };
      
        var options = {};
      
        var result = api.performItem("FileTransferActivity", properties, action, options);
      
      
        Write(Stringify(result));
    } catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }
</script>
```

Is there any particular reason why the script does not work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The error already told itself. Most likely you put a wrong File transfer activity ID, maybe you would want to let us know how you get this File transfer activity ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you put a wrong File transfer activity ID.

The following here is a simple way to get the File transfer activity ID:

Click to the File transfer activity in Automation Studio that you want find the ID. The string after the last slash `/` in your browser URL is the File transfer activity ID.

E.g. my browser URL looks like this:

`https://mc.s10.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Automation%20Studio/AutomationStudioFuel3/%23ActivityDetails/53/XXXXXXXXX`

The XXXXXXXXX part is the the File transfer activity Id (Object Id)

Comment: Thank you for the help this worked